# Datagridview muestra la longitud del nombre en lugar del nombre

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una ventana que muestre la lista de impresoras instaladas. Pero en lugar de mostar el nombre de la impresora, muestra la longitud de este. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
public partial class frmPrinters : Form
    {
        public BindingList<string> Impresoras = new BindingList<string>();
        public frmPrinters()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmPrinters_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bindSource = new BindingSource();
            for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
            {
                Impresoras.Add(PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i]);
            }

            bindSource.DataSource = Impresoras;
            grdPrinters.DataSource = bindSource;
        }

        private void btnCerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cuál es la estructura de `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo hice de una forma mas sencilla no se si te sirva, cree un datatable con una columna string y le agrego las impresoras, finalmente enlazo la tabla a la grid:

```
       DataTable dt = new DataTable("Impresoras");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("nombre", typeof(string)));
        for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i].ToString());
        }
        grdPrinters.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Gracias, lo he probado y ya funciona. Esta claro que  no puedo asignar una lista directamente a un DataSource.

Comment: Si te ha servido, por favor marcalo como respuesta

Comment: Como la marco como respuesta?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Es debido a que la clase `String` contiene la propiedad pública `Length` y cuando lo enlazas a tu `DataGridView` lo considera.

---

Para solucionar tu problema sería necesario implementar una clase que contiene la información de la impresora.

Por ejemplo:

Creación de clase `Impresora`:

```cs
public class Impresora
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Modificar la forma como obtienes la información:

```
private readonly BindingList<Impresora> _impresoras = new BindingList<Impresora>();

private void Printers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bindSource = new BindingSource();
    for (var i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
    {
        _impresoras.Add( new Impresora { Nombre = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i] });
    }

    bindSource.DataSource = _impresoras;
    grdPrinters.DataSource = bindSource;
}
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Clase String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)